# How to implement multi level sorting in javascript using lodash?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

The problem :
A job board with filter system where the users can set tags preference.

I need to sort the list of jobs based on the number of tags being matched, multiple jobs can have the same tag count and then I have to sort the most recent job within each tag count group.

My approach right now : I group the jobs based on their tag match count. I neglect the ones which have zero count. I proceed to sort each group with their date in descending order.
Finally merge the collections in the descending order of tag count.

Is there a better of doing this in lodash or plain javascript using functional programming like reduce, map, filter.
DateA < DateB < Date C and so  on...

```
Input:
[
  { tagCount: 2, date: DateA},
  { tagCount: 2, date: DateB},
  { tagCount: 1, date: DateC},
  { tagCount: 3, date: DateD},
]

Output:
[
  { tagCount: 3, date: DateD},
  { tagCount: 2, date: DateB},
  { tagCount: 2, date: DateA},
  { tagCount: 1, date: DateC}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.orderBy()` and state `['tagCount', 'date']` as the sorting properties, and `['desc', 'desc']` as the respective sort order for each of them:

the `desc` as the sort order:

```js
const input = [{ tagCount: 2, date: 'DateA'}, { tagCount: 2, date: 'DateB'}, { tagCount: 1, date: 'DateC'}, { tagCount: 3, date: 'DateD'}]

const result = _.orderBy(input, ['tagCount', 'date'], ['desc', 'desc'])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It's not giving the desired result...It's sorting according to date in the end..I need it to only sort with date within tagCount group as mentioned in the question...

Comment: Have you run the snippet?